# $π(x+y) - π(x) ≤ c·y/\ln(y)$ for some constant $c$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

(I posted [this question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3327182/21820) but it has had no answer for a year now so I would like to ask if anyone here can provide one.)

Thinking about the prime number theorem, I wondered whether it is known that there is some constant $c$ such that $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + c·y/\ln(y)$ for every integers $x,y > 1$. I read that experts believe $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + π(y)$ fails for some $y$, since [it fails for $y = 3159$ if the k-tuple conjecture holds](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/the-quest-for-narrow-admissible-tuples), but it is just barely false, so I am curious if it is known to be true if the inequality is relaxed by a constant factor. If so, is it also known that $π(x+y) ≤ π(x) + π(y) + c·\!\sqrt{y}·\ln(y)$ for some constant $c$? I simply do not know how to search for such conjectures, and neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) nor [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html) seem to state any results that would affirm or refute these two conjectures easily, so any references would be appreciated!

Comment: Montgomery and Vaughan (The large sieve, Mathematika, 1973)  showed that $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x) \le 2y/\log y$.

Comment: @Lucia: Thank you! I see it is (1.12) in [there](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/152543/mtks0025579300004708.pdf). Do you want to post that as an answer? And do you know about the second question? The "$c·\sqrt{y}·\ln(y)$" comes from the idea that, if the conjecture that $π(x+y) ≤ π(x)+π(y)$ is barely false but the error is bounded by $O(y/\ln(y))$, the next tighter plausible natural bound is $O(\text{Li}(y)-π(y))$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, [Montgomery and Vaughan](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/152543/mtks0025579300004708.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (*The Large Sieve*, Mathematika **20** (1973) 119–132, doi:[10.1112/S0025579300004708](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300004708)) showed an explicit version of the Brun--Titchmarsh inequality:
$$ 
\pi(x+y) - \pi(x) \le \frac{2y}{\log y}.
$$

The other question asked is likely false.  [Hensley and Richards](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa25/aa2548.pdf) (*Primes in intervals*, Acta Arithmetica **25** (1974) 375-391, [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/205282)) showed that the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuples conjecture contradicts the hypothesis that $\pi(x+y) -\pi(x) \le \pi(y)$.  In fact their paper establishes that (on the $k$-tuples conjecture) one has (for large fixed $y$, and infinitely many $x$)
$$ 
\pi(x+y) -\pi(x) \ge \pi(y) + (\log 2 -\epsilon) \frac{y}{(\log y)^2}. 
$$
Roughly the lower bound that they are obtaining is $2 \pi(y/2)$ (and some conjectural improvements over this are also discussed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is amazing; it means that on one hand it's known that $π(x+y)-π(x) ≤ 2·π(y)$ and that it's believed that for infinitely many $x,y$ we have $π(x+y)-π(x) ≥ 2·π(y/2)$.

Comment: @Lucia: does this inequality also hold true when $y$ is a function of $x$ like, say, $y=O(\log^{C}x)$ for some absolute positive constant $C$?